# incorrect fullscreen div size in 1366x768, but in full hd everything is fine

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for the ambiguous title but I really don't know how to explain this problem with a single sentence.
I downloaded a bootstrap template with this section:

```css
        header.masthead {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 150px;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
        color: white;
        background: url("../img/bg-pattern.png"), #00d8ff;
        background: url("../img/bg-pattern.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #3ba793, #0044ff);
        background: url("../img/bg-pattern.png"), linear-gradient(to left, #3ba793, #0044ff);
    }
      header.masthead .header-content {
        max-width: 500px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
        text-align: center; }
        header.masthead .header-content h1 {
          font-size: 30px; }
      header.masthead .device-container {
        max-width: 325px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto; }
        header.masthead .device-container .screen img {
          border-radius: 3px; }
      @media (min-width: 992px) {
        header.masthead {
          height: 100vh;
          min-height: 775px;
          padding-top: 0;
          padding-bottom: 0; }
          header.masthead .header-content {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            text-align: left; }
            header.masthead .header-content h1 {
              font-size: 50px; }
          header.masthead .device-container {
            max-width: 325px; } }
```

```html
<header class="masthead">
      <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100">
          <div class="col-lg-7 my-auto">
            <div class="header-content mx-auto">
              <h1 class="mb-5">SOME TEXT</h1>
              <a href="#download" class="btn btn-outline btn-xl js-scroll-trigger">SOME TEXT</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5 my-auto">
           <!--SOMETHING TO ADD-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

I tested the website in Chrome with a 1920x1080 monitor and everything is fine, `<header>` height is perfect and pressing F11 for full screen it adjusts the height, but now I'm using my laptop with 1366x768 and this won't happen. In fact only with F11 `<header>` height is fine, while with normal browser resolution it stay fixed at 1366x768, and I don't know why. I tried with Chrome and Edge.

I hope you got the problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: edited to insert snippet. try to remove `min-height: 775px;` to see if it works

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks!